# Securing a URL without credentials

Tags: security

I have a use case that I do not think is possible.  But I thought I would ask it to see if it is.

Here is the scenario:

> My company needs additional information from an order that was placed in our system.  To get that information we generate a form for the customer to fill out.  The form has most of the data pre-filled (to save the customer time filling out the form).  Only the missing data is empty.
>
> It is on the customer to login to our system to securely access this form and fill it out.
>
> Problem is that our customer does not always know the data that is needed.  They are a "middle man" so to speak.  So, they need to get the data from their customer (aka the Original Customer).

So the chain is: My company -> Middle Customer -> Original Customer

The Middle Customer has a login and can securely access our system.  But the Original Customer does not.  We have thousands of Middle Customers and they in turn can have tens to hundreds of Original Customers.  (Whom they don't really want us interacting with.)

The use case is that I need a way to allow the Middle Customer to securely share that form with the Original Customer even though we don't have any user credentials for said Original Customer.

Every type of security I can think of requires a shared secret of some kind.    With so many Original Customers and my company not having direct communication with them, trying to setup credentials for all the Original Customers seems to not be possible.

Seems like this is not possible with security as I know it. But I thought I would ask.  **Is there a way to secure a link without credentials?**

Comment: There are definitely several good ways to secure a link without username/password or shared secrets. I'm not quite certain I understand the flow, though. When you say "secure," against what? What would you consider a security breach here? Can you sketch out what the ideal flow would look like for you? I feel this is a very solvable problem, I'm just not quite picturing the problem you're solving.

Comment: Probably the most important question is whether you trust Middle to vouch for the identity of Original. If so, then you can create a long random value that you hand to Middle and they hand to Original, and that value, by itself, authenticates the user. (But as I say, I feel I'm missing something.)

Comment: @RobNapier - When I say "Secure" I mean that the pre-filled data in the form must not be seen by anyone other than Middle and those Originals that Middle says can see it.  (So, if someone else got the link and loaded it up and saw the pre-filled data that is a breach.)

Comment: @RobNapier - We do trust Middle to vouch for Original.  I like the idea of of creating a random value, but I then I need a secure way to communicate that to Original.  I can't let Middle send it to Original via email, it is not secure enough.  (This is patient/HIPPA data, so it is very bad if it is breached.)

Comment: But I assume that Original has some authentication via Middle, right? As a patient, I generally have to go to some patient portal to read medical data. They'd distribute the link there. Middle can also use OAuth to authenticate the user to you without you having to know the user at all; Sign-In With Apple works along these lines. (This still feels very solvable; I don't know if StackOverflow is the most effective medium for it, though.)

Comment: I can also imagine pretty simple crypto solutions based on some "well known customer id" like "last 4 SSN" if that kind of authentication is permitted (feels a little dicey merging SSN in there; but the concepts stands if there is any identifier that both Middle and Original know, even if you don't know it). Designing that kind of system gets into professional consulting territory though; I can point you in the right direction, but I definitely couldn't design a full crypto solution as a general SO answer; it's too special-purpose.

Comment: @RobNapier -  I appreciate you taking the time to think about it.  The current system (that I am trying to replace) is paper and fax based.  So I don't have any known authentication system.  The idea of using a known identifier is worth looking into.  I am also wondering if a Muti-Factor auth might work.  Some kind of phone based password dispenser.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Vaccano what did you end up with as a solution? I am facing a similar problem at my work.